# CSS Button is below where it should be

Tags: css

I have never created a search bar such as this one, but I'm trying to make a search bar, where the button is touching the input box. I have achieved this, but the button is lower than it should be, and I'm not sure why.

[image: Screenshot]

Above is what it currently looks like. As you can see, the button is lower than it should be.

Here is my css:

```
.searchBox {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.cf:before, .cf:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after{
    clear:both;
}

.cf{
    zoom:1;
}
.form-wrapper input {
    width: 285px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 6px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    background-color: #ededed; 
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; 
    color:#363636;
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #E8E8E8;
}

.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    width: 45px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #48A6D9;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}   

.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #4DAFE3;
    border: 0;
}

.form-wrapper button:active {
    border: 0;
}
```

And here is how I use the button:

```
<div class="searchBox">
    <form class="form-wrapper cf" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Search user..." required>
        <button type="submit">Go!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I fix this so the button is where it should be? (Beside the input area)

Thanks!

Comment: you might, for instance, set both form inputs to `float:left` - you currently have the button set to `float:right` but presumably this is not what you want to achieve. [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8tudbr2/). PS it is important to try to understand what your code is doing, piece by piece, before asking on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give `float:left` for both (input and button)

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mq38p5op/) it will help you